# How to program ATmega2560 chip

Tags: usb, avr, atmega, atmel

This is ATmega2560
http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega2560.aspx

How can you program this?
Using Arduino as ISP?
USBasp?

Also, since this chip in a QFN (I think this is what it's called), then how do you make the connections?

Is there something like an adaptor where you put in in?

Comment: The 2560 is also available in TQFP, no need to deal with no lead packs unless you have to.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/96238/2028

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an Arduino to program it, like any other ATMega chip.  You can also use a USBasp.  I suggest heading over to the Arduino website / forum / playground  where there are detailed instructions.

The chip is designed to be directly soldered to a circuit board using solder paste and a reflow oven or a reflow "rework" workstation.  There are QFN to DIP adaptors available - check eBay - but designing your own PCB and getting it manufactured is pretty cheap (and a good learning experience).

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier, visit the [Atmel Store](http://store.atmel.com/CBC.aspx?q=c:100112) and buy the MKII or the JTAGICE3. Don't bother with anything else.